# UICollectionReusableView Header not resizing on rotation - constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint, uicollectionreusableview

I have a UICollectionReusableView for a UICollectionView Header Section in code as follows:

```
    
    var headingLabel: UILabel!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       headingLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(12.0,12.0,frame.width,21.0))
       headingLabel.numberOfLines = 1
       headingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
       headingLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
       self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       self.addSubview(headingLabel)
    }
```

I just want the heading to be centered in the display.  This is fine so long as I don't rotate the device.  If I rotate the device, the label is no longer in the center of the screen.

My guess is this is super simple, I just can't seem to find the answer.  My assumption is that I could just programatically add constraints, but I can't quite work out how to do that.

Alternatively, I think there might be some way to force it to redo the headers on a layout change, but I couldn't get that working either.

Any pointers in the right direction would be hugely appreciated.

[image: Section Header Centered]

[image: After Rotation to Portrait]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invalidate the layout BEFORE the collectionView is re-laid out (which happens in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`), therefore you must invalidate it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    // Handle rotation
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents

class SectionHeaderAppointment:UICollectionReusableView {

var sectionHeaderlabel: UILabel!
var nameflatButton:MDCButton!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    print("Rotation")
     sectionHeaderlabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,  width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
     nameflatButton.frame = CGRect(x: (frame.width - (frame.width/3))/2, y: 6,  width: frame.width/3, height: frame.height - 8)
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? How does this answer the question? Please be specific.

Comment: Use layoutSubviews inside your UICollectionReusableView to update frame.